# Неправильный дамп PGSQL через PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pgsql

Когда создаю дамп через консоль, то всё работает. А когда пытаюсь сделать аналогичную операцию через PowerShell, дамп создаётся, но большего размера и потом не подключается. Через hex видно, что добавляются дополнительные 00.

CMD:

```
pg_dump.exe --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/Dump -E UTF-8 -F t > "C:\Dumps\Dump.tar.gz"
```

PS:

```
Invoke-Expression 'CMD /C pg_dump.exe --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/Dump -F t > "C:\Dumps\Dump.tar.gz"'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло добавление вывода в файл через -f вместо >.